# Creating new project (.net Core Web) Visual Studio 2017 Error: Unterminated string. Path TemplateInfo[40].Tags.auth

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Since yesterday I am getting a weird error when I try to create a new .Net Core Web project. The error I am getting:

[image]

It seems this is only the case for .Net Core projects (Console application .Net core also doesn't work but a regular .Net web project does work...

I looked online but it seems there is no documentation about this error whatsoever.

Some things I tried already:

- Repairing Visual Studio 2017
- Checked the log by running Devenv /log (Warning :

`Performance warning: String load failed. Pkg:{D15F5C78-D04F-45FD-AEA2-D7982D8FA429} (VisualBasicProjectSystemPackage) LANG:0409 ID:2&#x000D;&#x000A;`  )

**UPDATE**

I think I know what caused the problem. Prior to the problem I deleted my old user account (migrated the account so everything copied to a new user account), my guess is that Visual Studio also installs templates on my user account and with the removal of my old user account I also deleted some templates. The question however is, why is the .Net Core template the only one not working then?

Anyone know what causes this problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Removing Visual Studio and reinstalling it seems to fix the issue. Before reinstalling, make screenshots of all your settings and (manually) downloaded components.

Comment: I tried to uninstall VS and then reinstall but it doesn't worked :(

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, I tried to repair (multiple times) the installation but the problem wasn't solved.
In my case I didn't change user accounts.. I just uninstalled VS 2013 Ultimate, Unistalled VS 2015 (with some difficulty) and then installed VS2017..

Comment: Are you getting the error on all the templates or just the .NET Core template like I did? Make sure you delete all folders referencing to your old visual studio instances (2013, 15, 17).

Comment: I tried with different kind of projects but I see this exception only in the Core ones. If I create them externally using the command line I can work without any issue or limitation